# DNS/.htaccess files to redirect subdomain to specific folder

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, dns

I'm trying to redirect my subdomain to a flder. I think I have the .htaccess code from another post here. Something like:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^clients\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^ http://example.com/clients/root/app%{REQUEST_URI} [L,P]
```

What DNS settings should I set up for the clients. subdomain to tie it in with the .htaccess.

Comment: Dear Lewis Boyles-White, may you please [mark your answer as "accepted"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) if they helped you?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a CNAME to point `clients.example.com` to the same server as `example.com`. Then you need to make sure your webserver is setup to serve the `clients.example.com` in the same root as `example.com`.

Of, you can simply setup `clients.example.com`'s vhost to point to the `/clients/root/app/` folder instead. There's a directive called `DocumentRoot` that you'd use to point a vhost to a where it's root folder is.

In the case of the first instance, where both the main domain and subdomain point to the same root, you don't need to use the `P` flag:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^clients\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^ /clients/root/app%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

Is good enough and circumvents the need to go through mod_proxy.